# What is using so much of my disk space?

Tags: vps

I have a 768MB VPS, on which I host 1 website. That website has WordPress installed and a MyBB forum and it fills 22 GB in space. It shouldn't have more than 1 GB. And a few weeks ago it had 15 GB in space, so it's increasing even though I haven't added/uploaded anything. The email service is disabled and I've looked through the files on the website and didn't saw any file that could be responsible for so much space usage. Where else can I look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check for error logs. I had a Wordpress site that was constantly running out of disk space and it turned out to be a large error log. If this is the issue the first thing you do is fix the issue that is being logged as not doing so will result in this problem never going away.

Answer (score 1):

Login to the server and execute the command below. It will show the files which are in GB's. It will help you to investigate it further.

cd / ; find ./ -size +1000000000c

Answer (score 0):

Search for large logs. Also check to see if anyone has uploaded large (or multiple) files through the forum somehow.

Try backing up your server to your computer and see which folders are holding that much data. Also some servers backup the files to a archive which is on the server, which might increase space usage.